# AsyncStorage Multiget Array backslashes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I got this out put from asyncstorage multiget. why it get backslashes with its output?

```
Array [
  "defaultData",
  "\"{\\\"fullName\\\":\\\"asas\\\",\\\"livingCountry\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"monthlyIncome\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"height\\\":\\\"4\\\",\\\"weight\\\":\\\"12\\\"}\"",
]
```

I tried to convert it into object but it also getting that backslashes with its property.

```
Object {
  "obj": "{\"fullName\":\"asas\",\"livingCountry\":\"1\",\"monthlyIncome\":\"0\",\"height\":\"4\",\"weight\":\"12\"}",
}
```

Comment: in the first array for the second element you will need to JSON.parse() twice

Comment: How the data end up there in the first place?

Comment: in the object JSON.parse(variableName.obj) should do

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks that worked. Do you know what is the reason for that?

Comment: I used `let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(items[0][1]));` and thats worked for me. Don't know the reason. But it create a object what I wanted.

Comment: sorry i dont know how AsyncStorage Multiget works